# how to get value from select tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

Hi there i got little problem with Javascript. I populate dropdown menu with database record.

```
function selectCountry(){
    $result = @mysql_query("SELECT * from country");
    while($record = @mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<option value="'.$record['countryid'].'">'.$record['countryname'].'</option>';
    }
}
```

and now it's populated with datas, how can i get dropdown menu value in javascript. Here is my html code

```
<select name="dropdown" onchange="myFunction()">
<?php selectCountry(); ?>
</select>
```

when i write javascript function it's said *Cannot read property 'options' of null*

```
function myFunction(){
    var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    var elementValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(elementValue);
}
```

Comment: theres a reason why `mysql` is deprecated, you shouldnt omit the error msg because of it..in php 7.0, `mysql` is actually removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add id to your select

```
<select name="dropdown" onchange="myFunction()" id="dropdown">
                                                ^            ^
```

You are fetching the value based on `id` in script, but the `id` doesnot exists.

**Here is one more best solution**

```
<select name="dropdown" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

In script

```
function myFunction(val){    
   alert(val)
}
```

Fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NiranjanNRaju/NWbsj/80/)

Comment: i thinks declare <option> tag manually is not good solution it is depending on database record.

Comment: Did u check that?? Or adding id is fine for u??

Comment: No i haven't check it. first method /id/ is fine to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value directly by id using this, where "dropdown" is `<select>` id:

```
var elementValue = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
```

and if you get value by name you can use this, where "dropdown" is `<select>` name:

```
document.getElementsByName("dropdown")[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "this" as parameter to your myFunction() as it reads as

`<select name="dropdown" onchange="myFunction(this)">`

JavaScript treats "this" as current object(dropdown) into calling function

Now modify your JavaScript function as

`function myFunction(obj){`

```
    return obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
```

`}`